# Using shared transition animation form adapter class to another activity

Tags: android

I am using shared transition animation from my adapter class in my activity when I click on item it should go to another activity using shared element transition.

Below is my code:

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("contentTwo", hitModel.getLargeImageURL());
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context,holder.image3,"transition");
                context.startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());

            }
    });
```

When I am doing like this I am getting red line below `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context,holder.image3,"transition")`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: context have to be Activity. this could be the wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
```

Whith this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
```

Or this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
```

If doesn't work a please add more lines of the environment.

Comment: add all the lines of code or here you may see how to pass the activity to the adapter :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336048/why-does-my-android-adapter-not-have-the-getactivity-method